# Kubernetes cronjob - git pull else git clone

Tags: git, kubernetes, cron, yaml

Kubernetes cronjob can be used to update some volume with the latest data from a git repository.

```
containers:
      - name: hello
        image: alpine/git
        volumeMounts:
        - name: requirements
          mountPath: /workdir
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - cd /workdir/dashboard; git pull http://url..
```

But it is not ready to work from the box. If the volume is empty I need to do git clone first and only then do git pull each time.

But making bash if statement as a cronjob command doesn't work for some reason - cronjob will just fail.

`if cd /workdir/dashboard; then git pull http://url..; else git clone http://url..; fi`

logs are `fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)`

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Instead of using Git, can you put your content into a Docker image, and then update the `image:` tag in a Deployment?  What things do you expect to be in this volume?

Comment: "command doesn't work for some reason" -- what happens? Are there errors in the pod log?

Comment: @larsks fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
This same error is thrown when I just run cronjob without git clone first. So as far as I understand the command stops at git pull

Comment: @DavidMaze requirements.txt file.

Comment: That error sounds like you're running `git pull` instead of `git clone`. Possibly just debugging your script (maybe add `set -x`?) would let you discover the source of the problem. Maybe `/workdir/dashboard` exists but is not a git repository?

Comment: A Python `requirements.txt` file is part of your application source code; it doesn't belong in a volume at all.  Your underlying Docker image should say something like `COPY requirements.txt .` and then `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`; rebuild the image, and update the Deployment's `image:`, to update it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Its not a python application, it is how airflow chart made

Comment: @larsks it shoud become a git repo when git clone is executed. But this script doesn't reach clone command, the pod just fails

Comment: @Nazar, please include the output of `kubectl logs hello` and `kubectl describe pod hello`

Comment: @PawełGrondal 
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Started container hello
Back-off restarting failed container

Comment: @Nazar, please add the errors to your question. You can do this by editing your original post. It makes it easier for community to find all neccessary information in one place, rather then reading through the comments. Also, please include the output of `kubectl describe pod hello`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do a git pull and if the repo does not exist locally you can use the following snippet to only do the second command if the first one fails, i.e. repo not cloned yet

```
git pull || git clone $git-repo-url
```

Comment: I need to change working directory first. So taking into count this fact - isn't your command same as that if statement I have used myself?